# Rendering animation speed

Tags: animation

I am working on creating a scene with animals..three in the scene.  I have them walking across the room...I first set it up with different poses every 5 frames... rendered the animation at 24fps... when playing the animation video, it appears they are running across the floor..   I set it up again with every 10 frames, changed the poses...(changing the position of their legs and/or head..)  rendered it at 15fps.. they still appear to hurry across the room... 
    How can I make the animation look as if they are walking across the room a little slower.. little smoother flow...

I am learning this animation and modeling of animals...

thank you 
Barbara

Answer (score 8):

In the [*Dopesheet*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/DopeSheet) you could select all <kbd>A</kbd> and use scale <kbd>S</kbd>, to move the scaled keyframes use grab <kbd>G</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To slow down an animation you can space the keyframes using the Dopesheet.
The further away the keyframes are (the longer number of frames in between keyframes), the slower your objects will move.

[image]

To move the keyframes, select them and press <kbd>G</kbd> and drag them down the timeline.

[image]

Comment: Please explain how you go about moving the keyframes.

Comment: Select keyframes, then hit "g", then move. Move, rotate and scale have the same hotkeys as in the 3D-view, and is used the same way.