# How do I speed up Blender Game animation?

Tags: rendering, game-engine, physics, keyframes

I am using the Blender Game render for keyframing physics, but when I play it back, it is so slow (the keyframes are close to each other, the closest they can get, but it is still slow). Is there a way I can speed this up in the graph editor?

Also, and unrelated question:
After I keyframe with Blender Game, can I go back to Cycles Render without affecting the timeline?

Comment: Yes, you can switch back to cycles without affecting the keyframes. However note that there is a rigid body simulator built into normal blender now, so you don't need to use the game engine necessarily. The reason it appears slow is because the viewport defaults to 24 FPS, but the game engine defaults to 60 FPS.

Comment: @gandalf3 So if I increase the FPS, it will run faster..? Because I just need the physics frames faster

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rendering animation speed](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18185/rendering-animation-speed)

Comment: @MrSquer You are probably better off running the game engine at 24 FPS (you can change this in *properties > World settings > Physics*).

Comment: @RayMairlot The keyframes are one frame apart, so I don't think scaling will work really..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can speed up the playback of the animations by increasing the 'Animation Frame rate' speed in the Render properties editor.

[image]